# How to change headers in a CSV file with 'CSV' then save the new headers in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I came across the exact question I'm looking to answer: "[How do you change headers in a CSV File with FasterCSV then save the new headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/940774/3170942)"

Unfortunately, the answer is out of date because FasterCSV is no longer an available solution.

Here's the example code given as [an answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/940901/3170942):

```
require 'fastercsv'

input = File.open 'original.csv', 'r'
output = File.open 'modified.csv', 'w'
FasterCSV.filter input, output, :headers => true, :write_headers => true, :return_headers => true do |row|
  change_headers(row) if row.header_row?
end
input.close
output.close
```

But when I tried to implement the recommended solution in my own program I realized that Ruby no longer allows FasterCSV. And the command line said:

> Please switch to Ruby 1.9's standard CSV library.  It's FasterCSV plus
>   support for Ruby 1.9's m17n encoding engine.

So I then tried removing 'Faster' from everywhere it said "FasterCSV'. Except it gave me:

> undefined method `change_headers' for main:Object (NoMethodError)

What am I missing here?

Comment: You are calling this `change_headers` from main object. Is it a main object method?

Comment: No. I assumed that was part of the CSV library. Judging by your response, it's apparently not. Perhaps you can answer this.... code that would have worked with FasterCSV, should it run just fine in CSV? Or are there differences between them?

Comment: Yeah for this piece of code work perfectly, just change `FasterCSV.filter` for `CSV.filter`. Ruby 1.9 has adopted FasterCSV as its built-in CSV library so they should be compatible.

Comment: Okay so that answers my first question. I should expect the same behavior from the built-in CSV library as I would have expected from FasterCSV. Thanks Christian!